# Multer upload is not a function in swagger UI / Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger-ui, multer

I'm using Multer to make an upload file system in swagger UI.

I found this screenShot issue - **upload is not a function**

[image]

**This Is Catagory. uploads.js**

```
const multer = require("multer");
const Path = require("path");


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
                  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
                                    callback(null, "./uploads/categories");



                  },
                  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
                                    callback(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
                  }


});

const fileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
                  const acceptableExt = [".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"];
                  if (!acceptableExt.includes(Path.extname(file.originalname))) {


                                    return callback(new Error("Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!"));

                  }

                  const fileSize = parseInt(req.headers["content-length"]);

                  if (fileSize > 1048576) {
                                    return callback(new Error("File Size Big"));
                                    
                  }

                  callback(null, true);
};

let upload = multer({
                  storage: storage,
                  fileFilter: fileFilter,
                  fileSize: 1048576,
});

module.exports = upload.single("categoryImage");
```

**sorry, formater is not working.....**

**This Is My Category.service.js**

```
const { category } = require("../models/category.model");

async function createCategory(params, callback) {
                  if (!params.categoryName) {
                                    return callback(
          {
                   message: "Category Name Required",
              },
                  ""
                                    );
                  }


                  const model = new category(params);
                  model.save().then((response) => {
                                    return callback(null, response);
                  }).catch((error) => {
                                    return callback(error);
                  });

};
```

**This is my Category. controller.js**

```
const categoriesService = require("../services/category.service");
const upload = ("../middleware/category.upload");



exports.create = (req, res, next) => {
                  
   upload(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) {
         next(err);
      }
      else {    
         
         const path = req.file != undefined ? req.file.path.replace(/\\/g, "/"
         ) : "";

         var model = {
            categoryName: req.body.categoryName,
            categoryDescription: res.body.categoryDescription,
            categoryImage: path != "" ? "/" + path : "",
         };

         categoriesService.createCategory(model, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
               return next(error);
            }
            else {
               return res.status(200).send({  
                  message: "Success",
                  data: results,
               });
            }
         });
      }
   });
};
```

**this is my swagger.json**

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Grocery App",
    "description": "Grocery App - Flutter/NodeJs",
    "license": {
      "name": "MIT",
      "url": "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
    }
  },
  "host": "localhost:8000",
  "basePath": "/",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "Category",
      "description": "Category API"
    }
  ],
  "schemes": ["http"],
  "consumes": ["application/json"],
  "produces": ["application/json"],
  "paths": {
    "/api/category": {
      
      "get": {
        "tags": ["Category"],
        "summary": "Get all Categories",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "categoryName",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "description": "Category Name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "page",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "description": "Page Number",
            "type": "integer",
            "default": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "pageSize",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "description": "Page Size",
            "type": "integer",
            "default": 10
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ServiceResponse"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": ["Category"],
        "summary": "Create Category API",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "categoryName",
            "in": "formData",
            "description": "Category Name",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "categoryDescription",
            "in": "formData",
            "description": "Category Description",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "categoryImage",
            "in": "formData",
            "description": "Category Image",
            "type": "file"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ServiceResponse"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/api/category/{id}": {
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "in": "path",
          "required": true,
          "description": "Category Id",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "get": {
        "tags": ["Category"],
        "summary": "Category Details based on Category Id",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ServiceResponse"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "put": {
        "tags": ["Category"],
        "summary": "Update Category API",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "categoryName",
            "in": "formData",
            "description": "Category Name",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "categoryDescription",
            "in": "formData",
            "description": "Category Description",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "categoryImage",
            "in": "formData",
            "description": "Category Image",
            "type": "file"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ServiceResponse"
            }
          }
        }        
      },
      "delete": {
        "tags": ["Category"],
        "summary": "Delete Category API",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ServiceResponse"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Category": {
      "required": ["categoryName", "_id"],
      "properties": {
        "_id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "uniqueItems": true
        },
        "categoryName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "categoryDescription": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "categoryImage": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },   
    "ServiceResponse": {
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Category"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**Help Please How can I solve this ?**

Comment: I guess there is a spelling mistake, the file name is "Catagory.uploads.js", but while importing in "Category.controller.js" in "upload" variable. You have written "category.upload" instead of "Catagory.uploads". (Does that solve your problem?)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiz6V.png -please check this image

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = upload.single("categoryImage");
```

*in the above code just export `--upload`*

*this is the update code of above code*

```
module.exports = upload;
```